# Is there an equivalent of $exception for return values

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, watch-window

In the Visual Studio watch window you can put `$exception` and get details of the current exception, but is there an equivalent for the methods return value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# - and the answer is simply No. In VB.NET though, you can look for the name of the method in the Locals window, and that should be it. For reference, [see this blog post by JaredPar (from Microsoft)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2011/01/12/why-the-debugging-difference-between-c-and-vb-net-return-values.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

$eax will usually show the return for most basic types (for C++ anyway - I don't know if this applies to C#).

You may also find $err useful - it shows the current value of GetLastError() ("$err,hr" will try to show a text representation of the error value).

Comment: It does, but you have to use Debug + Windows + Registers.  No pseudo variable.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to work for C#. I can see the eax value, but I was hoping for something a bit more high level.

Comment: @Hans: `$eax` works in the watch window for C++ (but, it looks like the question is more for C# or managed code).

Answer (score 0):

You can now.

`$ReturnValue` in the Watches or Immediate windows.  Also, check the Autos window.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx